# Ordering users with most matching user's skills

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show recommended users to a user in descending order where skills match the most.

Issue is that I am storing skill in single field in this form

```
    user_skill
    musician,pop,singer
```

Note: this will be input musician,pop,singer..

so what I want to achieve I want to show users have all three skills at top,then those having two at last those having only one.

so out put will be like

```
 **user_name    skills**

 sam     musician,pop,singer
 smith   musician,pop,singer
 ali     musician,singer
 nasira  musicain,pop
 siri    musician
 taylor  pop
 andrew  singer
```

Can this be achieved by single mysql query?

If this not possible can this be done by php code.I don't want to change table structure as this will require lots of redo.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might be able to do with with SQL but the query would be so complex i probably wouldnt. On the php side you could iterate over the result set and tally the skills for each user_name within a given set of skills you are looking for, and then just sort them. However, the definition and attribution of these skills is a key part of you application, you should just normalize the tables now... its only going to become a larger refactor by putting it off.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do with with SQL but the query would be so complex i probably wouldnt.

On the php side you could iterate over the result set and tally the skills for each user_name within a given set of skills you are looking for, and then just sort them:

```
$desired = explode(',', $input);
$users = array();

// i presume you have the query worked out to find users with any one of input 
// skills attributed to them so lets say that $stmt is the PDO statement where you 
// have executed that query

while (false === ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
    $row['skills'] = explode(',', $row['skills']);
    // assign an array containing only skills that were in your $input
    // to $row['desired_skills']
    $row['desired_skills'] = array_intersect($desired, $row['skills']);
    $row['nb_desired_skills'] = count($row['desired_skills']);
    $user[] = $row;
}

usort($users, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b['nb_desired_skills'] - $a['nb_desired_skills'];
});

// now you can loop over $users and display the fields you need
```

However, the definition and attribution of these skills is a key part of you application, you should just normalize the tables now... its only going to become a larger refactor by putting it off.

Comment: Thank you.Let me try above.

Comment: Thanks Its worked..But you are right I should try to create another table.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to change table structure as this will require lots of redo.

I ***strongly (!)*** recommend you make a separate `skills` table, and link that to your `users` table using foreign keys. You will be infinitely thankful to yourself once your project gets even slightly more complex.

If you don't know how, I'm sure people on this site would help you with a script that does the conversion if you were to post another question.

**MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE skills
(
       name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

This way you can *easily* select users by most skills using a simple subquery (assuming you have a `users` table with an `id` column):

**MySQL**

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM skills
         WHERE user_id = u.id) AS num_skills
  FROM users u
 ORDER BY num_skills DESC;
```

---

**So why would you take this approach instead of relying on PHP?**

- Creates minimal extra overhead in database,
- ***significantly*** reduces chatter between database and webserver by not requiring to query the entire users table if you just want, for example, only the top 10 users,
- enables more complex and varying queries in the future easily.

The following MySQL snippet queries *only* those users who have a given skill (for example, "singer"), then sorts them in descdending order based on number of skills. The query does not return users with zero skills:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM skills
         WHERE user_id = u.id
           AND name = 'singer') AS num_skills
  FROM users u
 WHERE num_skills > 0
 ORDER BY num_skills DESC;
```

Of course, you can also search for skills by `id` just replace the second part of the `WHERE` clause inside the subquery with `AND id = 3`, which will query those users, who have a skill with ID of 3.

---

The next step towards a more optimal database would be creating a real `skills` table, which stores only the skills that you have registered in your database, and a `user_skills` table, that links it and the `users` table together.

This would enable you to ***significantly*** reduce database size on the long run, and be able to run complex but 'clean' queries that do not depend on the webserver.

Comment: Hi, I realized you are very right.Can you please let me know what query will be to achieve my requirement. Say I have above skills so I want to see users have most similar skills at top on my recommended page.The query you have written does not taking any skills in where clause.?

Comment: You can of course add a `WHERE` either to the main query, or to the subquery. Your problem did not require one if I understood it right. Would you like an example which does not list users below a certain skill count (`WHERE` in main query), or an example that ignores a certain skill (`WHERE` in subquery)?

Comment: BTW, the above queries create a skills table (first query), and do a `SELECT` that returns _all_ users in a descending order based on number of skills.

Comment: Yes Please I want the example where users having all or any skill like I have.Then order them in a way user have most matching skills at top then so on.So I assume in where clause I will pass skill's IDS... Not sure but like this
where user_skill_id ANY(3,4,5)..